# Unable to clear viewstate

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

Hi all I am assigning a Datatable for viewstate on certain operations like on each button I will assign a row and will bind that to datatable and assigning that datatable to viewstate. I am having a gridview which was binded with datatable that I was creating. In that I am having a delete option on deleting a row I cleared the Viewstate and assign it with new datattable

```
DataTable dtPayment = new DataTable();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
   }
 }

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] == null)
  {
    dtPayment.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(string));
    dtPayment.Columns.Add("PaymentMode", typeof(string));
    dtPayment.Columns.Add("TransactionAmount", typeof(string));
    dtPayment.Columns.Add("BankCharges", typeof(string));
    dtPayment.Columns.Add("Particulars", typeof(string));

     DataRow dr = dtPayment.NewRow();
     dr["Id"] = 1;
     dr["PaymentMode"] = "Cheque";
     dr["TransactionAmount"] = txtAmount.Text;
     dr["BankCharges"] = "";
     dr["Particulars"] = "";
     dtPayment.Rows.Add(dr);
     ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtPayment;
     grd.DataSource = dtPayment;
     grd.DataBind();
  }
 else
 {
    AddNewRowToGrid("Cheque", txtAmount.Text);
 }
```

}

```
protected void grd_Deleting(object sender, DeletingEventArgs e)
{
   dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
   int iIndex;
   iIndex = grd.FocusedRowIndex;
   dt.Rows[iIndex].Delete();
   dt.AcceptChanges();
   ViewState.Remove("CurrentTable");
   ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
   grd.DataSource = dt;
   grd.DataBind();
}

 protected void AddNewRowToGrid(string strPaymntMode, string transAmount)
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        //SetPreviousData();
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                    drCurrentRow["Id"] = i + 1;
                    drCurrentRow["PaymentMode"] = strPaymntMode;
                    drCurrentRow["TransactionAmount"] = transAmount;
                    drCurrentRow["BankCharges"] = "";
                    drCurrentRow["Particulars"] = "";
                    rowIndex++;
                }
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;
                grd.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                grd.DataBind();
            }
        }

    }
```

But when viewing it after one delete the datatable remains same as per the one with previous values can some one tell where I went wrong

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind the `grid` again after deleting row from `datatable`. Also make sure if you bind the gridview in page_load then it is in if(!Page.IsPostBack).

```
protected void grd_Deleting(object sender, DeletingEventArgs e)
{
   dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
   int iIndex;
   iIndex = grd.FocusedRowIndex;
   dt.Rows[iIndex].Delete();
   dt.AcceptChanges();
   ViewState.Remove("CurrentTable");
   ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
   //You have to bind the grid with new data table.
   GridView1.DataSource =  dt;
   GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Yeah I do that for 1st record it is working fine, but on deleting second record the previous values are retained in the viewstate

Comment: Check if you are not binding the data table on page_load and that is over writing the changes you made in grd_Deleting event.

Comment: In page_load I am not binding the grid, on button click events I have binded the gridview by checking the viewstate and all

Comment: Check out my edit like that I will have several buttons on each button click I will check for viewstate null or not if null I will create new else I will add a row

Comment: I think dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow); in method AddNewRowToGrid would be last statement of loop?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27326/discussion-between-learner-and-adil)

Answer (score 0):

Check for your gridview bind method call inside of !isPostBack in page load event??

For see below

```
void page_load()
{
if(!IsPostBack)    
{
// call Bind grid method
}
}
```